# Jquery accessing iframe document content in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access iframe document content means whole document content (from <!DOCTYPE> declaration to </html> all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parent page and the iframe are on the same domain you could access elements like this:

```
var someDiv = $("#id_of_iframe").contents().find("#someDiv");
```

If the iframe is on a different domain than the parent page then you cannot access its contents due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions.